# SQL Server Counting Same Result Aggregation Function

Tags: sql-server, database

I am using SQL Server and this is my current table:

| id | ref_id | Drug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Drug A |
| 2 | 1 | Drug B |
| 3 | 2 | Drug A |
| 4 | 2 | Drug B |
| 5 | 3 | Drug C |

When I run this code

```
SELECT
    ap.ref_id, 
    STRING_AGG(ap.Drug, '+') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ap.Drug) AS groups
FROM
    myTable AS ap
GROUP BY 
    ap.ref_id
```

The output is

| ref_id | Drug |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Drug A+Drug B |
| 2 | Drug A+Drug B |
| 3 | Drug C |

but I can't count same drug result, in the future I need to be like this:

| count | Drug |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Drug A+Drug B |
| 1 | Drug C |

any suggestion? or is there something wrong with my logic?

Comment: if drugs are the same in the result set, then which ref_id you need to consider? or simply you need a count of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    COUNT(*) AS [Count],
    STRING_AGG(ap.Drug, '+') AS Drug
FROM  myTable AS ap
GROUP  BY ap.ref_id
ORDER BY [Count] DESC
```

Comment: thank you very much, you saved my life too!~

Comment: Good :) . Please mark as an answer, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rely on a subquery in this case, such as :

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(ap2.ref_id), 
   ap2.groups
FROM (
  SELECT
    ap.ref_id , 
    STRING_AGG(ap.Drug, '+') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ap.Drug) AS groups
  FROM
    myTable AS ap
  GROUP BY 
    ap.ref_id
) ap2
GROUP BY groups
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a048929d51c84f188a819dc493216e94) if you want to try it yourself.

I'd be interested to know if anyone come up with a simpler solution though.

Comment: Well, you are welcome, but I think eriksv88 actually came up with a better answer